# How to add days to Date?

Tags: javascript, date

How to add days to current `Date` using JavaScript? Does JavaScript have a built in function like .NET's `AddDay()`?

Answer (score 1789):

You can create one with:-

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

var date = new Date();

console.log(date.addDays(5));
```

This takes care of automatically incrementing the month if necessary. For example:

**8/31** + 1 day will become **9/1**.

The problem with using `setDate` directly is that it's a mutator and that sort of thing is best avoided. ECMA saw fit to treat `Date` as a mutable class rather than an immutable structure.

Comment: These solutions do not handle the case when you need to know whether the hour will be different after `days` many 24-hour days.  Adjust `getDate` / `setDate` / `days` to `getTime` / `setTime` / `days * 24*60*60*1000` if you want time to detect DST.

Comment: Simplified: `Date.prototype.addDays=function(d){return new Date(this.valueOf()+864E5*d);};`

Comment: @Duncan Are you sure this is the same as the above? This one simply adds 24 hours, but [one day is not always 24 hours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). I guess the question is how to increment the date part by 1 day, without changing the time part.

Comment: @Tamás Bolvári: see the answer I supplied below.  :)

Comment: ```864E5``` for some reason I prefer to write ```24*60*60``` in my code :)

Comment: @MichalStefanow That always comes off to me as: "I couldn't be bothered to do the math myself". To each their own though.  :)

Comment: Guys, do not use method of adding 864E5 because this does not take daylight saving difference where days can be 23 or 25 hours.

Comment: For those of you worried about Daylight Savings -- Don't.    These algorithms change the underlying date, not how the date is interpreted.  DST is implemented in the getters and setters of the date -- the getters to subtract an hour in the summer, and the setter to add that hour back during the summer to normalize the time. But only when using an absolute hour -- relative hours don't need to be interpreted.  This is why date math works. IMHO...

Comment: While it might be a matter of principle to not mutate the date on which the method is called, it's not sensible. All *set* methods mutate the date and return the time value, for this method to not change the date and to return a new date object instead of the time value is not pragmatic.

Comment: Just to provide an example for @sbrbot's point: Once you convert to microseconds (with valueOf() or getTime()), DST will start to mess up your calculations. e.g., using @Duncan's prototype try this and you'll lose an hour:

`d = new Date( 2016, 10, 4 )`

`d.addDays(3)`

Comment: is it working with float number like:  `addDays(3.0)` ?@AnthonyWJones

Comment: This is not working if days are a decimal number: Works on Chrome but Firefox does not change hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: Hi very nice s oltion although the date doesn't actually change, so if u call date.addDays(5); date.addDays(5); the result will be the same, I tried to make the solution Date.prototype.addDays=function(days){var date = new Date(this.valueOf());date.setDate(date.getDate()+days);this.setDate(date.getDate());return this;} but it doesn't update the month, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: DAYLIGHT SAVINGS - sorry for caps, but it's important and needs to stand out :)

Comment: That should be `24*60*60*1000`

Comment: Some minutes are not 60 secondes ... and some year are not 365,25 days ... just saying 

Comment: Sometimes the solution here does not work

Comment: I got some weird results with this function and figured out that it's when passing in `days` as a string. So I would add a `parseInt()` to the solution to make sure that doesn't happen. It's hard to troubleshoot, there won't be an error but the returned date for me was sometime 9 months ahead when `days==3`, but it all worked when `days==2`. No idea why, but `parseInt()` will care for that.

Comment: @Duncan's comment is correct if (and only if) your date represents a UTC date/time. AnthonyWJones's answer is correct if (and only if) your date represents local time. The thing to understand is that a JavaScript Date represents an absolute moment in time, and they DO NOT have a time zone, so you must choose the correct method to use based on the time zone that you know (in your mind) the date represents.

Comment: Extending native prototypes is an anti pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: This solution is not correct if the local time zone crosses a daylight saving time switch, e.g. in a CEST firefox:
`d = new Date("Mon, 25 Oct 2021 00:00:00 GMT")`
`d.addDays(7).toUTCString()`
yields `"Mon, 01 Nov 2021 01:00:00 GMT"`

Comment: Typescript doesn't like this one I'm afraid

Comment: Why not to do it short?
`Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
            this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
}`

Comment: Why are mutators are best avoided?

Comment: @Enriqe Because that would be mutation of the object which is undesirable.

Comment: @user7868 dates are essentially a scalar value, it represents a fixed point in time.   Consider calling a function that accepts a date.  The function should treat the date as immutable, it can't know how else that date is used in code and so should not change it.

Answer (score 1131):

**Correct Answer**:

```
function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}
```

**Incorrect Answer**:

This answer *sometimes* provides the correct result but very often returns the wrong year and month. The only time this answer works is when the date that you are adding days to happens to have the current year and month.

```
// Don't do it this way!
function addDaysWRONG(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(); // not instatiated with date!!! DANGER
  result.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}
```

**Proof / Example**

[Check this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sparebytes/XrWzq/)

```js
// Correct
function addDays(date, days) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
}

// Bad Year/Month
function addDaysWRONG(date, days) {
    var result = new Date();
    result.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return result;
}

// Bad during DST
function addDaysDstFail(date, days) {
    var dayms = (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    return new Date(date.getTime() + dayms);    
}

// TEST
function formatDate(date) {
    return (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
}

$('tbody tr td:first-child').each(function () {
    var $in = $(this);
    var $out = $('<td/>').insertAfter($in).addClass("answer");
    var $outFail = $('<td/>').insertAfter($out);
    var $outDstFail = $('<td/>').insertAfter($outFail);
    var date = new Date($in.text());
    var correctDate = formatDate(addDays(date, 1));
    var failDate = formatDate(addDaysWRONG(date, 1));
    var failDstDate = formatDate(addDaysDstFail(date, 1));

    $out.text(correctDate);
    $outFail.text(failDate);
    $outDstFail.text(failDstDate);
    $outFail.addClass(correctDate == failDate ? "right" : "wrong");
    $outDstFail.addClass(correctDate == failDstDate ? "right" : "wrong");
});
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 14px;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table, td, th {
    border:1px solid black;
}
td {
    padding: 2px;
}

.wrong {
    color: red;
}
.right {
    color: green;
}
.answer {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">DST Dates</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Input</th>
            <th>+1 Day</th>
            <th>+1 Day Fail</th>
            <th>+1 Day DST Fail</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>03/10/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11/03/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>03/09/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11/02/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>03/08/2015</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11/01/2015</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">2013</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Input</th>
            <th>+1 Day</th>
            <th>+1 Day Fail</th>
            <th>+1 Day DST Fail</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>01/01/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>02/01/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>03/01/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>04/01/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>05/01/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>06/01/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>07/01/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>08/01/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>09/01/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10/01/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11/01/2013</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12/01/2013</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">2014</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Input</th>
            <th>+1 Day</th>
            <th>+1 Day Fail</th>
            <th>+1 Day DST Fail</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>01/01/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>02/01/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>03/01/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>04/01/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>05/01/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>06/01/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>07/01/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>08/01/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>09/01/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10/01/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11/01/2014</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12/01/2014</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">2015</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Input</th>
            <th>+1 Day</th>
            <th>+1 Day Fail</th>
            <th>+1 Day DST Fail</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>01/01/2015</td></tr>
        <tr><td>02/01/2015</td></tr>
        <tr><td>03/01/2015</td></tr>
        <tr><td>04/01/2015</td></tr>
        <tr><td>05/01/2015</td></tr>
        <tr><td>06/01/2015</td></tr>
        <tr><td>07/01/2015</td></tr>
        <tr><td>08/01/2015</td></tr>
        <tr><td>09/01/2015</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10/01/2015</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11/01/2015</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12/01/2015</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @bzlm, Yes essentially the same. It just doesn't modify the Date prototype. I also wanted to point out the flaws in the main answer.

Comment: The accepted answer was edited a fortnight ago to point out its flaws. Do you think it needs further editing? If so, how?

Comment: @bzlm: Yes, I believe the note should read "this approach fails if the 'from' date is not in the same year **or month** as the **current date**". I still worry that users will glance over the answer and not read the warning since it doesn't stand out. Thanks.

Comment: At line result.setDate(date.getDate() + days); you need to change 

date.getDate() to result.getDate()  if you are passing value not the date exactly .. otherwise there is an exception

Comment: @UsmanY, I updated the code as you suggested. You only got that exception because you didn't pass a Date object into the function. Now the function will accept date-formatted strings. `"mm/dd/yyyy"`

Comment: @sparebytes i have up-voted though :)  and thanks for taking care of this, I just try to help others if they get same exception. so things should be open to people

Comment: Great answer on a confusing SO thread. It would be really great to add to the answer *why* the wrong way fails behind the scenes.

Comment: @bzlm please re-edit the correct answer. Now it's ok. This is leading to confusing notes about the correct answer saying that won't be useful.

Comment: I think, even if this work it is not correct. There is no such constructor for Date: _var result = new Date(date);_, see [http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp). Even if this usually work, sometimes can lead to wrong results because of conversion to string and vice versa. It should be _var result = new Date(date.getTime());_

Comment: @Marcin, I agree that `new Date(date.getTime());` is better but I don't think there is any case where `new Date(date)` will give a wrong answer due to string conversion. If anyone can provide an example I'd like to see it. How crazy would it be for a date constructor to not read the string the same way it is formatted to by default. From what I understand, the user's local timezone and date format settings should have no affect on the correctness of this function.

Comment: Dude this answer is awesome! I have been doing the incorrect approach by incrementing the `1st of June` with `1 day` and getting the `2nd of May` which was driving me crazy...

Comment: This answer works.  I wrote it first as new Date() and the value was off by a month if the starting date wasn't the current month

Comment: I only get invalid date using this method

Comment: for current Date, why not just 
`daysToAdd = 10;`
`date = new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * daysToAdd));`

Comment: @AnkitBalyan, See other answers. It may not work correctly due to Daylights Savings Time

Comment: This is not working if days are a decimal number: Works on Chrome but Firefox does not change hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: Has anything changed in these years? JSFiddle shows all green for `+1 Day DST Fail
` and all red for `+1 Day Fail`. Chrome/Edge v94. 

On the other note - Such a simple operation requires me to read so much information and a whole community to solve. :facepalm:

Comment: Sorry, forgot to attach screenshot for previous comment: https://i.imgur.com/rtDPUdv.png
Actually if I look at the results - the `+1 Day Fail` solution is incorrect test for someone with different locale settings that lives outside of US...

Comment: Can someone explain the difference in code between the correct and incorrect version?

Comment: @JimmyDillies, the difference is `new Date();` vs `new Date(date)`. The first creates with the **current** year, month, and day; and then changes the day. The second creates a date with the **given** year, month, day, and then changes the day.

Comment: Best answer. (Javascript date handling is crazy)

Answer (score 316):

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
```

Be careful, because this can be tricky.  When setting `tomorrow`, it only works because its current value matches the year and month for `today`.  However, setting to a date number like "32" normally will still work just fine to move it to the next month.

Comment: I did edit some, but you can see that this version still predated his answer.  Ah, well.

Comment: Yeah? But what is this? (ran on March 31st, 2010):
today = new Date();
tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
alert(tomorrow.getMonth());

Says "3". alert(tomorrow); is correct... Why???

Comment: @sims month is 0 indexed.  Month 3 is April

Comment: Why the need to create 2 separate date objects? Why not simply use the same date object: `var d = new Date(); d.setDate( d.getDate() + 1 );`?

Comment: This approach doesn't work across years. If your starting date is from a few years ago, `getDate()` returns the _day of that year_. Then, calling `setDate` sets the day in the _current year_. So it is *NOT* a good general solution. [@AnthonyWJones's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/563442/24874) actually works correctly.

Comment: Creating two `Date` objects with `new` will fail if performed just when switching between months. `today.getDate()` would return the last day of the month, while `tomorrow`s month would already be in the next month. So `tomorrow` would end up completely wrong.

Comment: @DrewNoakes—your assertion that it doesn't work across years is wrong. *getDate* returns the day in the month, not "day of that year". E.g. `var d = new Date(2015,11,30);d.setDate(d.getDate() + 370)` gives 3 Jan 2017 which crosses 2 years.

Comment: *"Be careful, because this can be tricky. When setting "tomorrow", it only works because it's current value matches the year and month for "today"."* What do you mean by this? Adding dates to a day works just fine across months (or even years)... I suspect I'm just not reading what you wrote the way you meant it.

Comment: I don't know why this answer is not more high in the answers. Much more clean and simple.

Answer (score 175):

These answers seem confusing to me, I prefer:

```
var ms = new Date().getTime() + 86400000;
var tomorrow = new Date(ms);
```

getTime() gives us milliseconds since 1970, and 86400000 is the number of milliseconds in a day. 
Hence, ms contains milliseconds for the desired date.

Using the millisecond constructor gives the desired date object.

Comment: This solution doesn't take daylight savings into account.  So, for example, this will return the same date, 23 hours later:
    `new Date(new Date('11/4/2012').getTime() + 86400000)`

Comment: @NoahMiller The problem which you bring up could be a feature not a bug!  Adding 24 hours per day is sometimes the right thing to do, with the goal of knowing the resulting time based on DST.  The date that your example returns has a time value of 11pm on November 4th which is what 24 hours later is on that particular day.  The original poster asked about datetime which would seem to indicate some desire for correct times of the day.  This answer is correct if you are in the case when your goal is the time 24 hours later.

Comment: I agree Noah, var d2 = new Date(d1.valueOf() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) does what it says, adds a full day worth of ticks to a date.

Comment: This is absolutely correct for some cases (for example for 1 day cookies) and a simpler solution than most of the others. I dont get why it has so many downvotes and so few upvotes :/

Comment: Agree with Matmarbon that Corey Alix's answer is better.  I implemented the highest ranked answer from Sparebytes but got erroneous results; Corey Alix's answer worked

Comment: This answer is correct if (and only if) your date represents a UTC date/time or if you only want to add 24-hour days. Some other answers (AnthonyWJones's) are correct if (and only if) your date represents local time. The thing to understand is that a JavaScript Date represents an absolute moment in time, and they DO NOT have a time zone, so you must choose the correct method to use based on the time zone that you know (in your mind) the date represents.

Comment: That's a highly underappreciated solution! It solves the problem for the different months!

Answer (score 154):

My simple solution is:

```
nextday=new Date(oldDate.getFullYear(),oldDate.getMonth(),oldDate.getDate()+1);
```

this solution does not have problem with daylight saving time. Also, one can add/sub any offset for years, months, days etc.

```
day=new Date(oldDate.getFullYear()-2,oldDate.getMonth()+22,oldDate.getDate()+61);
```

is correct code.

Comment: Note: this resets time to 00:00:00 (can be an issue or not)

Comment: Doesn't work on the last day of any month, as you say. Makes this unusable on 12 days of the year. Sounds like a nightmare to debug!!!

Comment: No Drew, it is usable for all days on year. You can put date offset bigger than 31 or month offset bigger than 12 and this function will recalculate it as day in next month or month in next year. So for example: nextday=new Date(oldDate.getFullYear(),oldDate.getMonth(),oldDate.getDate()+40); is perfectly well code.

Comment: there is getMonth()+22 - what you think will it work!?

Comment: I Agree, use this way. We just had a bug because of daylight saving time because we were using `setDate`.

Comment: I have tried the method above and got strange results when adding 1000s of days. It gets solved by adding all the parameters of the Date constructor: Year, Month, Day,Hour, Minute,Second

Answer (score 79):

Here is the way that use to add days, months, and years for a particular date in Javascript.

```
// To add Days
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 5);

// To add Months
var m = new Date();
m.setMonth(m.getMonth() + 5);

// To add Years
var y = new Date();
y.setFullYear(y.getFullYear() + 5);
```

Answer (score 63):

Try

```
var someDate = new Date();
var duration = 2; //In Days
someDate.setTime(someDate.getTime() +  (duration * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Using setDate() to add a date wont solve your problem, try adding some days to a Feb month, if you try to add new days to it, it wont result in what you expected.

Comment: No, this should not be marked as the correct answer since this solution assumes that every day has 24*60*60*1000 seconds but it does not (daylight saving)!

Comment: Any evidence about the 'Feb' problem with `setDate()`?  Is it this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497637/javascript-setdate-returning-wrong-dates

Comment: +1 This SHOULD be marked as the correct answer. I believe that "daylight saving" is about **presentation** and not about **value**, which is just the number of milliseconds. From **value**-point of view - day is CONST number of millisecs, while in terms of **presentation** it may vary.

Comment: @disfated—this is not the correct answer. The day going out of daylight saving has 25 hours, but this method only adds 24 so the date will be the same. Using 24hrs to represent a day works if UTC methods are used instead, but why bother when using *setDate* is more convenient? ;-)

Answer (score 52):

Just spent ages trying to work out what the deal was with the year not adding when following the lead examples below.

If you want to just simply add n days to the date you have you are best to just go:

> myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + n);

or the longwinded version

```
var theDate = new Date(2013, 11, 15);
var myNewDate = new Date(theDate);
myNewDate.setDate(myNewDate.getDate() + 30);
console.log(myNewDate);
```

This today/tomorrow stuff is confusing. By setting the current date into your new date variable you will mess up the year value. if you work from the original date you won't.

Comment: Reading all the answers around until I find this jewel here. Now that makes sense. Amazing that the today/tomorrow thing was copied in almost all the answers, when it does not make sense at all and it is not "for readibility and clarity" as the author says in the most upvoted answer -in the most upvoted comment-, it is confusing and a bad practice and wrong

Answer (score 50):

The simplest approach that I have implemented is to use Date() itself.
`

```
const days = 15; 
// Date.now() gives the epoch date value (in milliseconds) of current date 
nextDate = new Date( Date.now() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

`

Comment: You should use NicoESIEA's answer if you care about DST (which you should)

Comment: This by far is the most elegant solution to the problem because it takes care of the fact that it handles the nasty situation of setting days beyond that of the month. You could literally right the function like...function addTime(years, month, day). If you want to go crazy with it you could add the hours, minutes, seconds and the milliseconds. I used to do it a lot in Unity for keeping track of the time in game because it used the Epoch method.

Answer (score 35):

```
int days = 1;
var newDate = new Date(Date.now() + days * 24*60*60*1000);
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaRjxy?editors=001)

```js
var days = 2;
var newDate = new Date(Date.now() + days * 24*60*60*1000);

document.write('Today: <em>');
document.write(new Date());
document.write('</em><br/> New: <strong>');
document.write(newDate);
```

Comment: Upvote for not requiring an intermediate date variable.

Comment: this is the best answer because it doesn't have mutation

Comment: Not every day has 24h, it fails for DST and leap seconds.

Answer (score 31):

If you can, use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). JavaScript doesn't have very good native date/time methods. The following is an example Moment's syntax:

```js
var nextWeek = moment().add(7, 'days');
alert(nextWeek);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Reference: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Comment: asks for a built-in solution

Comment: @kpull1 the asker did not restrict the solution domain by asking if a built-in solution exists.

Comment: Modern note: 
Moment.js is _incredibly_ heavy to add for such a small purpose. It's several hundred KB, and isn't webpack-friendly out of the box.

Comment: Our preferred library is date-fns.  Webpack-friendly, fast, and treats Dates as immutable.

Comment: @LukeWilliams never heard of date-fns until now. will check it out. thanks.

Comment: @JoshuaComeau moment.min.js = 51k.

Comment: @birdus according to Bundle Phobia, it's actually 217kb minified. https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=moment@2.19.2

Comment: I imagine there are different builds that cut out i18n options you don't need, but the default NPM package is quite large.

Comment: @JoshuaComeau If you download it from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.min.js, it takes up 53,248 bytes on disk. I imagine that's the whole ball o' wax, but I don't know. Anyway, whatever. It's not a big deal.

Answer (score 22):

the simplest answer is, assuming the need is to add 1 day to the current date:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var numberOfDayToAdd = 1;
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + numberOfDayToAdd );
```

To explain to you, line by line, what this code does:

1. Create the **current date** variable named currentDate. By default "new Date()" automatically assigns the current date to the variable.
2. Create a variable to save the **number of day(s) to add** to the date (you can skip this variable and use directly the value in the third line)
3. **Change the value** of Date (because Date is the number of the month's day saved in the object) by giving the same value + the number you want. The switch to the next month will be automatic

Comment: This is my answer. The code is legible and explicit. Not too short and no extraneous parts. The explanation is quite complete. Having a link to the MDN Date page would make it perfect.

Answer (score 21):

I created these extensions last night:
you can pass either positive or negative values;

example:

```
var someDate = new Date();
var expirationDate = someDate.addDays(10);
var previous = someDate.addDays(-5);


Date.prototype.addDays = function (num) {
    var value = this.valueOf();
    value += 86400000 * num;
    return new Date(value);
}

Date.prototype.addSeconds = function (num) {
    var value = this.valueOf();
    value += 1000 * num;
    return new Date(value);
}

Date.prototype.addMinutes = function (num) {
    var value = this.valueOf();
    value += 60000 * num;
    return new Date(value);
}

Date.prototype.addHours = function (num) {
    var value = this.valueOf();
    value += 3600000 * num;
    return new Date(value);
}

Date.prototype.addMonths = function (num) {
    var value = new Date(this.valueOf());

    var mo = this.getMonth();
    var yr = this.getYear();

    mo = (mo + num) % 12;
    if (0 > mo) {
        yr += (this.getMonth() + num - mo - 12) / 12;
        mo += 12;
    }
    else
        yr += ((this.getMonth() + num - mo) / 12);

    value.setMonth(mo);
    value.setYear(yr);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: The .addDays() method does not work for dates that cross daylight saving time boundaries.

Comment: This is one of the better answers here because you (correctly) use the number of millis since the epoc to represent dates/times, and add amounts of millis for adjustments... Why then did you not keep this up for "addMonths"!? And why no add year? Did you get bored?

Comment: Other than months, time periods can be represented by static numbers.  But months can be four different lengths.  Also, any time period length from Days and higher may have variable length at DST, so you can't use time-based addition anymore without another level of complexity.  I added the addYears(), and I fixed addMonths().

Answer (score 20):

A solution designed for the [pipeline operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Pipeline_operator):

```js
const addDays = days => date => {
  const result = new Date(date);

  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);

  return result;
};
```

Usage:

```js
// Without the pipeline operator...
addDays(7)(new Date());

// And with the pipeline operator...
new Date() |> addDays(7);
```

If you need more functionality, I suggest looking into the [date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) library.

Answer (score 16):

Without using the second variable, you can replace 7 with your next x days:

```
let d=new Date(new Date().getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Answer (score 16):

Short:

```js
function addDays(date, number) {
  const newDate = new Date(date);
  return new Date(newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + number));
}

console.log({
  tomorrow: addDays(new Date(), 1)
});
```

Advance:

```js
function addDays(date, number) {
  const newDate = new Date(date);
  return new Date(newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + number));
}

function addMonths(date, number) {
  const newDate = new Date(date);
  return new Date(newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + number));
}

function addYears(date, number) {
  const newDate = new Date(date);
  return new Date(newDate.setFullYear(newDate.getFullYear() + number));
}

function getNewDate(dateTime) {
  let date = new Date();
  let number = parseInt(dateTime.match(/\d+/)[0]);

  if (dateTime.indexOf('-') != -1)
    number = (-number);

  if (dateTime.indexOf('day') != -1)
    date = addDays(date, number);
  else if (dateTime.indexOf('month') != -1)
    date = addMonths(date, number);
  else if (dateTime.indexOf('year') != -1)
    date = addYears(date, number);

  return date;
}

console.log({
  tomorrow: getNewDate('+1day'),
  yesterday: getNewDate('-1day'),
  nextMonth: getNewDate('+1month'),
  nextYear: getNewDate('+1year'),
});
```

With fix provide by [jperl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11758901/jperl)

Comment: However, this will modify the date object you pass to your functions. If you do this `addDays(today, 1)`, today will now be tomorrow.

`function addDays(date, number) {
  const newDate = new Date(date)
  return new Date(newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + number));
}`

Comment: Why not `return newDate`? Why is this double-wrapping is used?

Answer (score 15):

The simplest solution.

```js
 Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
   this.setDate(this.getDate() + parseInt(days));
   return this;
 };

 // and then call

 var newDate = new Date().addDays(2); //+2 days
 console.log(newDate);

 // or

 var newDate1 = new Date().addDays(-2); //-2 days
 console.log(newDate1);
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution. If we're extending the Date class, then it makes better sense that the Date instance is itself updated.

Answer (score 15):

to substract **30** days use (24h=86400000ms)

```
new Date(+yourDate - 30 *86400000)
```

```js
var yourDate=new Date();
var d = new Date(+yourDate - 30 *86400000) 

console.log(d)
```

Comment: When trying to calculate date time always remember that date time in based on milliseconds in computer science, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time#Retrieving_system_time) new Date(+yourDate + 30 * (24*60*60*1000))

Answer (score 15):

You can try:

```
var days = 50;

const d = new Date();

d.setDate(d.getDate() + days)
```

This should work well.

Comment: I upvoted this, but the true one liner is
new Date( (new Date()).setDate((new Date()).getDate() + 1) )

Answer (score 13):

You can use JavaScript, no jQuery required:

```
var someDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6;
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 
Formatting to dd/mm/yyyy :

var dd = someDate.getDate();
var mm = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = someDate.getFullYear();

var someFormattedDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;
```

Comment: Would like to vote for this because this answer gives the correct month as date.getMonth() ranges from 0 to 11 and needs to be incremented by 1 as mentioned in this solution.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks Jason for your answer that works as expected, here is a mix from your code and the handy format of AnthonyWJones :

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days){
    var ms = new Date().getTime() + (86400000 * days);
    var added = new Date(ms);
    return added;
}
```

Comment: It does not take into account daylight saving when there's more or less than 86400000 seconds in a day and can result in logical error (program bug) in your code.

Comment: Sometimes that's needed.  The eBay API has x-day auctions which are 24-hour based so your item will end at a different time than it goes up if DST status changes mid-auction.  In that case you need to use this type of function to avoid logical errors.

Answer (score 12):

Late to the party, <strike>but if you use `jQuery` then</strike> there's an excellent plugin called Moment:

http://momentjs.com/

```
var myDateOfNowPlusThreeDays = moment().add(3, "days").toDate();
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

And lots of other good stuff in there!

Edit: jQuery reference removed thanks to aikeru's comment

Comment: moment does not need jQuery :)

Comment: Even better in that case!!

Comment: Yes, after futzing around with Plain ol' JS for too long, I used Moment , and it just works(tm)!

Comment: Why would you want to use plugin when a few lines of JS will do?

Comment: @frenchie because, what starts as a few lines of JS and because clearly your application is manipulating days, dates and time related information, it'll soon be a few 1000 lines of JS, then you'll be asked to localise the app across 12 languages and timezones and you'd wished you had started out with something like moment ;)

Answer (score 12):

As simple as this:

```
new Date((new Date()).getTime() + (60*60*24*1000));
```

Comment: While this does add UTC days, it uses local methods and doesn't allow for local days that aren't 24 hours long, which happens when the timezone offset changes (e.g. in and out of daylight saving).

Answer (score 11):

Old I know, but sometimes I like this:

```
function addDays(days) {
    return new Date(Date.now() + 864e5 * days);
}
```

Comment: This one makes the most sense to me.  It's simple, elegant and doesn't fall pray to issues moving over months/years.

Comment: Simplest answer presented.  Building on this, the prototype 'addDays' would be the following: `Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {return new Date(this.getTime() + (864e5 * days));};`

Comment: Not every day has 24h, it fails for DST and leap seconds.

Answer (score 11):

I had issues with daylight savings time with the proposed solution.

By using `getUTCDate` / `setUTCDate` instead, I solved my issue.

```
// Curried, so that I can create helper functions like `add1Day`
const addDays = num => date => {
  // Make a working copy so we don't mutate the supplied date.
  const d = new Date(date);

  d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + num);

  return d;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Why so complicated?

Let's assume you store the number of days to add in a variable called days_to_add.

Then this short one should do it:

```
calc_date = new Date(Date.now() +(days_to_add * 86400000));
```

With Date.now() you get the actual unix timestamp as milliseconds and then you add as many milliseconds as you want to add days to.
One day is 24h*60min*60s*1000ms = 86400000 ms or 864E5.

Comment: This works! And is actually smart, and short. 
I tested to see, if you add 30 days or 45 days, and if it calculates correctly and skips the correct months, and seems to be fine. 
The way this is done is what I was looking for, and using the "out of the box" js date function is the way to go, not complicating it, just using what already exists! Thumbs up! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

No, javascript has no a built in function, but
you can use a simple line of code

```
timeObject.setDate(timeObject.getDate() + countOfDays);
```

Answer (score 9):

The mozilla docs for setDate() don't indicate that it will  handle end of month scenarios.
See [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)

setDate()

- Sets the day of the month (1-31) for a specified date according to local time.

That is why I use setTime() when I need to add days.

Comment: I would link to the ECMAScript docs, but they are released in PDF ;(

Comment: Re "*mozilla docs for setDate() don't indicate that it will handle end of month scenarios*". The "docs" have been updated so now they do. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Generic prototype with no variables, it applies on an existing Date value:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
    return new Date(this.valueOf() + days * 864e5);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I guess I'll give an answer as well:
Personally, I like to attempt to avoid gratuitous variable declaration, method calls, and constructor calls, as they are all expensive on performance. (within reason, of course)
I was going to leave this as just comment under the Answer given by @AnthonyWJones but thought better of it.

```
// Prototype usage...
Date.prototype.addDays = Date.prototype.addDays || function( days ) {
    return this.setTime( 864E5 * days + this.valueOf() ) && this;
};

// Namespace usage...
namespace.addDaysToDate = function( date, days ) {
    return date.setTime( 864E5 * days + date.valueOf() ) && date;
};

// Basic Function declaration...
function addDaysToDate( date, days ) {
    return date.setTime( 864E5 * days + date.valueOf() ) && date;
};
```

The above will respect DST. Meaning if you add a number of days that cross DST, the displayed time (hour) will change to reflect that.
Example:
Nov 2, 2014 02:00 was the end of DST.

```
var dt = new Date( 2014, 10, 1, 10, 30, 0 );
console.log( dt );                  // Sat Nov 01 2014 10:30:00
console.log( dt.addDays( 10 ) );    // Tue Nov 11 2014 09:30:00
```

If you're looking to retain the time across DST (so 10:30 will still be 10:30)...

```
// Prototype usage...
Date.prototype.addDays = Date.prototype.addDays || function( days ) {
    return this.setDate( this.getDate() + days ) && this;
};

// Namespace usage...
namespace.addDaysToDate = function( date, days ) {
    return date.setDate( date.getDate() + days ) && date;
};

// Basic Function declaration...
function addDaysToDate( date, days ) {
    return date.setDate( date.getDate() + days ) && date;
};
```

So, now you have...

```
var dt = new Date( 2014, 10, 1, 10, 30, 0 );
console.log( dt );                  // Sat Nov 01 2014 10:30:00
console.log( dt.addDays( 10 ) );    // Tue Nov 11 2014 10:30:00
```

Answer (score 7):

Extending prototype in javascript [may not be a good idea](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/5ch66r/why_is_extending_native_objects_such_as_string/), especially in professional codebases.

What you want to do is extend the native `Date` class:

```js
class MyCustomDate extends Date {

  addDays(days) {
    const date = new MyCustomDate(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
  }
  
}

const today = new MyCustomDate();

const nextWeek = today.addDays(7)

console.log(nextWeek)
```

This way, if one day Javascript implements a native `addDays` method, you won't break anything.

Answer (score 6):

I use something like:

```
new Date(dateObject.getTime() + amountOfDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Works with day saving time:

```
new Date(new Date(2014, 2, 29, 20, 0, 0).getTime() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Works with new year:

```
new Date(new Date(2014, 11, 31, 20, 0, 0).getTime() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

It can be parametrized:

```
function DateAdd(source, amount, step) {
  var factor = 1;
  if (step == "day") factor = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  else if (step == "hour") factor = 60 * 60 * 1000;
  ...
  new Date(source.getTime() + amount * factor);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:**
Instead of `setTime()` (or `setHours()`) you could do it this way:

```
Date.prototype.addDays= function(d){
  this.setDate(this.getDate() + d);
  return this;
};

var tomorrow = new Date().addDays(1);
```

**Old:**

Instead of using `setTime()` you can use `setHours()`:

```
Date.prototype.addDays= function(d){
    this.setHours(this.getHours() + d * 24);
    return this;
};

var tomorrow = new Date().addDays(1);
```

See [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xepscvta/)...

Comment: following this logic you could also add one day ;) `d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);`

Answer (score 5):

Very simple code to add days in date in java script.

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + prompt('how many days you want to add write here'));
alert(d);
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a [**setDate**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) and a [**getDate**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) method, which allow you to do something like this :

```
var newDate = aDate.setDate(aDate.getDate() + numberOfDays);
```

If you want to both subtract a number of days and format your date in a human readable format, you should consider creating a custom `DateHelper` object that looks something like this :

```js
var DateHelper = {
    addDays : function(aDate, numberOfDays) {
        aDate.setDate(aDate.getDate() + numberOfDays); // Add numberOfDays
        return aDate;                                  // Return the date
    },
    format : function format(date) {
        return [
           ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2),           // Get day and pad it with zeroes
           ("0" + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),      // Get month and pad it with zeroes
           date.getFullYear()                          // Get full year
        ].join('/');                                   // Glue the pieces together
    }
}

// With this helper, you can now just use one line of readable code to :
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// 1. Get the current date
// 2. Add 20 days
// 3. Format it
// 4. Output it
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
document.body.innerHTML = DateHelper.format(DateHelper.addDays(new Date(), 20));
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9fpzcghg/22/))

Answer (score 4):

I am using the following solution.

```
var msInDay = 86400000;
var daysToAdd = 5;
var now = new Date();
var milliseconds = now.getTime();
var newMillisecods = milliseconds + msInDay * daysToAdd;
var newDate = new Date(newMillisecods);
//or now.setTime(newMillisecods);
```

Date has a constructor that accepts an int. This argument represents total milliseconds before/after Jan 1, 1970. It also has a method setTime which does the same without creating a new Date object.

What we do here is convert days to milliseconds and add this value to the value provided by getTime. Finally, we give the result to Date(milliseconds) constructor or setTime(milliseconds) method.

Comment: Not every day has 24h, it fails for DST and leap seconds.

Comment: Stephan, does any other library account for that?

Comment: `now.setDate(now.getDate() + days);` automatically handles DST changes. And I have to correct, leap seconds are ignored in JS timestamps.

Answer (score 3):

Our team considers [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) the best library in this space.  It treats dates as **immutable** ([Moment.js will probably never adopt immutability](https://maggiepint.com/2016/06/24/why-moment-js-isnt-immutable-yet/)), it's faster, and can be loaded modularly.

```
const newDate = DateFns.addDays(oldDate, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with this kind of functions, I solve it with parseInt()

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(dias) {

    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(parseInt(date.getDate()) + parseInt(dias));
    return date;
}

Date.prototype.addMonths = function(months) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setMonth(parseInt(date.getMonth()) + parseInt(months));
    return date;
}


Date.prototype.addYears = function(years) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setFullYear(parseInt(date.getFullYear()) + parseInt(years));
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    //the_day is 2013-12-31
    var the_day = Date.UTC(2013, 11, 31); 
    // Now, the_day will be "1388448000000" in UTC+8; 
    var the_next_day = new Date(the_day + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    // Now, the_next_day will be "Wed Jan 01 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0800"
```

Comment: I believe this wouldn't work with daylight saving times, leap seconds, or other timezone changes causing a day to not have 86400s.

Comment: This is the one that is correct. Date.UTC makes the difference. The only thing to that needs caution is that month starts from 0.

Answer (score 2):

For those using Angular:

Just do:

```
$scope.booking.totTijd.setMinutes($scope.booking.totTijd.getMinutes()+15);
$scope.booking.totTijd.setDate($scope.booking.totTijd.getDate() + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your custom helper function here

```
function plusToDate(currentDate, unit, howMuch) {

    var config = {
        second: 1000, // 1000 miliseconds
        minute: 60000,
        hour: 3600000,
        day: 86400000,
        week: 604800000,
        month: 2592000000, // Assuming 30 days in a month
        year: 31536000000 // Assuming 365 days in year
    };

    var now = new Date(currentDate);

    return new Date(now + config[unit] * howMuch);
}

var today = new Date();
var theDayAfterTommorow = plusToDate(today, 'day', 2);
```

By the way, this is generic solution for adding seconds or minutes or days whatever you want.

Comment: Even assuming that a day has 86400 seconds can be incorrect, assuming that there are no leap years can lead to serious errors.

Comment: ...And also in case of daylight saving settings, difference between two day is not always 24h.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get this done is using **date-fns** library.

```
var addDays = require('date-fns/add_days')
addDays(date, amount)
```

The documentation is available in this link [here](https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/addDays). You can also get this done using **moment.js**. The reference link is [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: There are already answers with hundreds of votes showing how to do this in one line with the native API. Why on earth would you suggest a whole library?

Comment: I actually wanted to expose these libraries that can perform such tasks with ease. Also I've mentioned the reference links of 2 such libraries so that anyone who looks into this may want to manipulate Date objects in other ways. I thought of contributing this issue in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

```
date d = new Date() // current date

date tomorrow = d.setMonth(d.getMonth(),d.getDate()+1) // return a date incremented by 0 months and 1 day
```

Comment: I changed the line after I realized that with 0 was creating the a date starting from January

Answer (score 2):

```
new Date(Date.now() + 2000 * 86400)
```

This snippet adds two days to the current date using the "2000" argument. You can tweak the number of days by updating the "2000" value in the second argument.

You can use this single line format to add days to the current date using the native JavaScript date.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this approach to get the right date in one line to get the time plus one day following what people were saying above.

```
((new Date()).setDate((new Date()).getDate()+1))
```

I just figured I would build off a normal `(new Date())`:

```
(new Date()).getDate()
> 21
```

Using the code above I can now set all of that within `Date()` in `(new Date())` and it behaves normally.

```
(new Date(((new Date()).setDate((new Date()).getDate()+1)))).getDate()
> 22
```

or to get the `Date` object:

```
(new Date(((new Date()).setDate((new Date()).getDate()+1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe there's no cut'n'paste solution in this thread after **5 years!**
SO: To get the same time-of-day regardless of summertime interference:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days)
    {
    var dat = new Date( this.valueOf() )

    var hour1 = dat.getHours()
    dat.setTime( dat.getTime() + days * 86400000) // 24*60*60*1000 = 24 hours
    var hour2 = dat.getHours()

    if (hour1 != hour2) // summertime occured +/- a WHOLE number of hours thank god!
        dat.setTime( dat.getTime() + (hour1 - hour2) * 3600000) // 60*60*1000 = 1 hour

    return dat
or
    this.setTime( dat.getTime() ) // to modify the object directly
    }
```

There. Done!

Comment: You should really avoid assigning to `prototype` of built-ins, as this is considered a bad practice and can lead to bugs. Consider using a function or a wrapper class around a built-in instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
function addDays(n){
    var t = new Date();
    t.setDate(t.getDate() + n); 
    var month = "0"+(t.getMonth()+1);
    var date = "0"+t.getDate();
    month = month.slice(-2);
    date = date.slice(-2);
     var date = date +"/"+month +"/"+t.getFullYear();
    alert(date);
}

addDays(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some implementations to extend Date
https://gist.github.com/netstart/c92e09730f3675ba8fb33be48520a86d

```
/**
 * just import, like
 *
 * import './../shared/utils/date.prototype.extendions.ts';
 */
declare global {
  interface Date {
    addDays(days: number, useThis?: boolean): Date;

    addSeconds(seconds: number): Date;

    addMinutes(minutes: number): Date;

    addHours(hours: number): Date;

    addMonths(months: number): Date;

    isToday(): boolean;

    clone(): Date;

    isAnotherMonth(date: Date): boolean;

    isWeekend(): boolean;

    isSameDate(date: Date): boolean;

    getStringDate(): string;
  }
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days: number): Date {
  if (!days) {
    return this;
  }
  this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
  return this;
};

Date.prototype.addSeconds = function(seconds: number) {
  let value = this.valueOf();
  value += 1000 * seconds;
  return new Date(value);
};

Date.prototype.addMinutes = function(minutes: number) {
  let value = this.valueOf();
  value += 60000 * minutes;
  return new Date(value);
};

Date.prototype.addHours = function(hours: number) {
  let value = this.valueOf();
  value += 3600000 * hours;
  return new Date(value);
};

Date.prototype.addMonths = function(months: number) {
  const value = new Date(this.valueOf());

  let mo = this.getMonth();
  let yr = this.getYear();

  mo = (mo + months) % 12;
  if (0 > mo) {
    yr += (this.getMonth() + months - mo - 12) / 12;
    mo += 12;
  } else {
    yr += ((this.getMonth() + months - mo) / 12);
  }

  value.setMonth(mo);
  value.setFullYear(yr);
  return value;
};

Date.prototype.isToday = function(): boolean {
  const today = new Date();
  return this.isSameDate(today);
};

Date.prototype.clone = function(): Date {
  return new Date(+this);
};

Date.prototype.isAnotherMonth = function(date: Date): boolean {
  return date && this.getMonth() !== date.getMonth();
};

Date.prototype.isWeekend = function(): boolean {
  return this.getDay() === 0 || this.getDay() === 6;
};

Date.prototype.isSameDate = function(date: Date): boolean {
  return date && this.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear() && this.getMonth() === date.getMonth() && this.getDate() === date.getDate();
};

Date.prototype.getStringDate = function(): string {
  // Month names in Brazilian Portuguese
  const monthNames = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'];
  // Month names in English
  // let monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  const today = new Date();
  if (this.getMonth() === today.getMonth() && this.getDay() === today.getDay()) {
    return 'Hoje';
    // return "Today";
  } else if (this.getMonth() === today.getMonth() && this.getDay() === today.getDay() + 1) {
    return 'Amanhã';
    // return "Tomorrow";
  } else if (this.getMonth() === today.getMonth() && this.getDay() === today.getDay() - 1) {
    return 'Ontem';
    // return "Yesterday";
  } else {
    return this.getDay() + ' de ' + this.monthNames[this.getMonth()] + ' de ' + this.getFullYear();
    // return this.monthNames[this.getMonth()] + ' ' + this.getDay() + ', ' +  this.getFullYear();
  }
};


export {};
```

Answer (score 0):

2.39KB minified. One file. https://github.com/rhroyston/clock-js

```js
console.log(clock.what.weekday(clock.now + clock.unit.days)); //"wednesday"
console.log(clock.what.weekday(clock.now + (clock.unit.days * 2))); //"thursday"
console.log(clock.what.weekday(clock.now + (clock.unit.days * 3))); //"friday"
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rhroyston/clock-js/master/clock.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function addDays(date,days) {        
      var one_day=1000*60*60*24; 
      return new Date(date.getTime()+(days*one_day)).toLocaleDateString(); 
    }
```

Comment: Don't use this, in case of daylight saving setting this doesn't work because day difference is not 24h. I did the same mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Use [js-joda](https://github.com/js-joda/js-joda). It is an awesome immutable date and time library for **javascript**. Here is an excerpt from its cheat-sheet.

Add 17 days to today

```
LocalDate.now().plusDays(17);
```

You can also build the desired date from now multiple operations at once.

```
LocalDate.now()
  .plusMonths(1)
  .withDayOfMonth(1)
  .minusDays(17);
```

Or:

```
var d = LocalDate.parse('2019-02-23'); 
d.minus(Period.ofMonths(3).plusDays(3)); // '2018-11-20'
```

Answer (score 0):

My test exemple can do adition an minus in the same instance of Date Object.

```html
Date.prototype.reset = function()
{
    let newDate = new Date(this.timeStamp)
    this.setFullYear        (newDate.getFullYear())
    this.setMonth           (newDate.getMonth())
    this.setDate            (newDate.getDate())
    this.setHours           (newDate.getHours())
    this.setMinutes     (newDate.getMinutes())
    this.setSeconds     (newDate.getSeconds())
    this.setMilliseconds    (newDate.getMilliseconds())
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days)
{
      this.timeStamp = this[Symbol.toPrimitive]('number')
      let daysInMiliseconds = (days * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
      this.timeStamp = this.timeStamp + daysInMiliseconds
      this.reset()
}

Date.prototype.minusDays = function(days)
{
      this.timeStamp = this[Symbol.toPrimitive]('number')
      let daysInMiliseconds = (days * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
      if(daysInMiliseconds <= this.timeStamp)
      {
          this.timeStamp = this.timeStamp - daysInMiliseconds
          this.reset()
      }
       
}

var temp = new Date(Date.now())// from now time

console.log(temp.toDateString())
temp.addDays(31)
console.log(temp.toDateString())
temp.minusDays(5)
console.log(temp.toDateString())
```

Answer (score -2):

I sum hours and days...

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days){
    days = parseInt(days, 10)
    this.setDate(this.getUTCDate() + days);
    return this;
}

Date.prototype.addHours = function(hrs){
    var hr = this.getUTCHours() + parseInt(hrs  , 10);
    while(hr > 24){
      hr = hr - 24;
      this.addDays(1);
    }

    this.setHours(hr);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

For everybody who don't know how to make it work : there is a full working code it's not perfect but you can copy past it and it's working.

In InDesign creat a `.jsx` in the startup scripts folder in `"Program Files\Adobe\Adobe InDesign 2021\Scripts\startup scripts"`.

You can us the Extendscript Toolkit CC in the creative cloud to make it and paste this:

The restart indesign and `jjmmyyyy`+30 should be in the texte variable.
this will show the date like this `jj/m/yyyy` idk how to make it show `24/07/2021` insted of `24/7/2021` but goodenough for me .

```
    #targetengine 'usernameVariable'
    function addVariables(openEvent) 
    {  
    var doc = openEvent.parent;  
    while ( doc.constructor.name != "Document" )  
      {  
    if ( doc.constructor.name == "Application" ){ return; }  
        doc = doc.parent;  
      }  
    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime


    var someDate = new Date();
    var numberOfDaysToAdd = 30;
    someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 


    var dd = someDate.getDate();
    var mm = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = someDate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;  

      createTextVariable(doc, "jjmmyyyy+30", someFormattedDate);  
    }
    function createTextVariable(target, variableName, variableContents)  
    {  
    var usernameVariable = target.textVariables.itemByName(variableName);  
    if (!usernameVariable.isValid)  
      {  
        usernameVariable = target.textVariables.add();  
        usernameVariable.variableType = VariableTypes.CUSTOM_TEXT_TYPE;  
        usernameVariable.name = variableName;  
      }  
      usernameVariable.variableOptions.contents = variableContents;  
    }  
    app.addEventListener('afterOpen', addVariables);
```

Answer (score -8):

## the same answer:  [How to add number of days to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

```
    function DaysOfMonth(nYear, nMonth) {
        switch (nMonth) {
            case 0:     // January
                return 31; break;
            case 1:     // February
                if ((nYear % 4) == 0) {
                    return 29;
                }
                else {
                    return 28;
                };
                break;
            case 2:     // March
                return 31; break;
            case 3:     // April
                return 30; break;
            case 4:     // May
                return 31; break;
            case 5:     // June
                return 30; break;
            case 6:     // July
                return 31; break;
            case 7:     // August
                return 31; break;
            case 8:     // September
                return 30; break;
            case 9:     // October
                return 31; break;
            case 10:     // November
                return 30; break;
            case 11:     // December
                return 31; break;
        }
    };

    function SkipDate(dDate, skipDays) {
        var nYear = dDate.getFullYear();
        var nMonth = dDate.getMonth();
        var nDate = dDate.getDate();
        var remainDays = skipDays;
        var dRunDate = dDate;

        while (remainDays > 0) {
            remainDays_month = DaysOfMonth(nYear, nMonth) - nDate;
            if (remainDays > remainDays_month) {
                remainDays = remainDays - remainDays_month - 1;
                nDate = 1;
                if (nMonth < 11) { nMonth = nMonth + 1; }
                else {
                    nMonth = 0;
                    nYear = nYear + 1;
                };
            }
            else {
                nDate = nDate + remainDays;
                remainDays = 0;
            };
            dRunDate = Date(nYear, nMonth, nDate);
        }
        return new Date(nYear, nMonth, nDate);
    };
```

Comment: You'll need to update your leap year check - if the year is divisible by 100 and not by 400, it's not a leap year (2000 was; 2100 won't be)